# What is the purpose of the "normal level protection" permission?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-permissions

What is the purpose the "normal" permission level if these permissions are automatically granted by the Android system? This seems like an unnecessary step. The other permission levels require user consent or some other additional criteria to be present, and therefore make sense in terms of design intent. Why do I need to ask for permission if it's granted 100% of the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general protection level characterizes the potential risk implied in the permission and indicates the procedure the system should follow when determining whether or not to grant the permission to an application requesting it.

> Normal - The default value. A lower-risk permission that gives
>   requesting applications access to isolated application-level features,
>   with minimal risk to other applications, the system, or the user. The
>   system automatically grants this type of permission to a requesting
>   application at installation, without asking for the user's explicit
>   approval (though the user always has the option to review these
>   permissions before installing).

Such permissions are required just to inform the user that the application is using such featured (For now). In the future those permission level group can be treated in another way.

Comment: Great, thank you. The key phrase is "... though the user always has the option to review these permissions before installing." In essence, this is an informational flag ... makes sense now!

Answer (score -1):

Its put in to let the user know exactly what the application is doing. The user can see these before installing - and may choose not to install your app!

Comment: "Its put in to let the user know exactly what the application is doing." this is wrong. I gave Facebook permission to my gallery and microphone but I have absolutely no idea what it's doing with those permissions. (this is just an example)

Comment: "I gave Facebook permission to my gallery and microphone". Exactly my point. An app which doesn't list microphone as a permission absolutely cannot access the microphone.
Of course, my use of the word "exactly" may not be entirely accurate - I meant the user will know if an app is using his mic or not. (as an example)

Comment: No, a permission doesn't tell a user that an app is using a mic or not. A permission only tells that an app **CAN** use the microphone.

Comment: An app which **doesn't** list microphone as a permission absolutely **cannot** access the microphone. Why would an app request microphone permission without having an intention of using it?

Comment: "Its put in to let the user know exactly what the application is doing" Facebook has the permission to use my microphone. That does not mean I know what they're doing now that they have the permission. Android Permissions only tell what an app **CAN** do, not what it's exactly (or pick any other word you like such as, "probably") do